# Does this site accept relationship questions?

Tags: support, scope

Since Health Stack Exchange is about health, does it accept questions on relationships as a part of *psychological* help?

Comment: No. Psychology.SE does exist, you might also try Interpersonal Skills.

Comment: Area 51, here I come. @Narusan

Comment: @JackJohansson Sorry, I don't understand (although I like the rhyme). Are you going to propose such a site?

Comment: Why @Narusan ???

Comment: relationship is usually not related to Health, and if it is, it id about the human psychology (hence this SE site)

Comment: @Narusan Yes. That's exactly what I meant, if not already purposed :)

Comment: There's an interpersonal skills beta site, and cognitive sciences beta site - check those out.  Relationships impact health, certainly, but this site's scope includes more the science or clinical aspects of psychology